# I get a status code of 200 for records being updated and the record fields still remain the same

Tags: apex

I created a custom endpoint to update a list of org contacts. I am getting a response of 200 and my success error code but the Name on the records are still the same.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Contact/*')
global with sharing class restresource {
    public restresource() {

    }
    @HttpPut
    global static void updateContacts(List<Contact> updateContacts) {
        RestResponse res = RestContext.Response;
        List<Contact> contactsToUpdateInDb = new List<Contact>();
        Map<Id, Contact> existingContacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([Select Id, FirstName, LastName from Contact]);
        for (Contact cont : updateContacts){
            if(existingContacts.containsKey(cont.id)){
                Contact record = existingContacts.get(cont.id);
                record.FirstName = !String.isBlank(cont.FirstName) ? cont.FirstName : record.FirstName;
                record.LastName = !String.isBlank(cont.LastName) ? cont.LastName : record.LastName;
                contactsToUpdateInDb.add(record);
            }
        }
        try {
            update contactsToUpdateInDb;
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Records updated successfully');
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('An Error Has occured While trying to update the records: ' + e.getMessage());
            }  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is both *disastrously* inefficient and implemented incorrectly. It will almost certainly break the second you deploy it to production, on either the Query Rows or Apex CPU Time limits. The first is because you query every Contact in the org (can't do that), and the second is because you are using an N^2 search algorithm that loops every Contact against every other Contact.

That loop, by the way, is also wrong:

```
                for (Contact insertedContact : Contacts){
                    for (Contact orgContact : Contacts){
                        if(orgContactIds.contains(insertedContact.Id)){
                            orgContact.FirstName = insertedContact.FirstName;
                            orgContact.LastName = insertedContact.LastName;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

You didn't compare the two Contacts *with each other*, you just asked if the inbound Contact has an Id that's also present in the org, and then overwrote the Contact record you have in the inner loop - which may not be the corresponding Contact.

---

You should delete essentially all of this code and just use the [`upsert` operation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm). Since you can perform an upsert [via the native REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm#!), you do not need to - and should not - write any Apex code at all.

Comment: I am playing around and learning things on my own and writing custom endpoints is something I want to do. I know the org has its own end points but I would like to learn to make things on my own. I also edited the code.

Comment: It's still N^2. See [this post](https://www.ktema.org/2019/11/04/quick-look-computational-complexity-apex/) (disclaimer: my blog) for an introduction to why that's a bad idea, and some ways to address it.

Comment: That was actually a good article. I absolutely forgot about map.I have updated the code and it works.